# Having a logical issue with recursion-based N-nested for loops

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, dictionary, nested

I've searched and found similar problems, but they all didn't seem to fit with mine. Basically, I need to write a recursive function that nests a loop N times and prints everything only on the very last loop. If you can find another solution to the problem, that would be great.

```
0 = *
1 = +
2 = ABC
3 = DEF
...
8 = STU
9 = VWXYZ
```

Here is the full code: http://pastebin.com/2YdQ693N

Here is a hard-coded N=3 example:

```
//sout is a vector<string>

for(int i = 0; i < sout[0].size(); i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < sout[1].size(); j++)
    {
        for(int k = 0; k < sout[2].size(); k++)
        {
            cout << sout[0][i] << sout[1][j] << sout[2][k] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

the following output of this particular example (input is "123"):

```
+AD
+AE
+AF
+BD
+BE
+BF
+CD
+CE
+CF
```

The closest I got before coming here was a recursion function similar to this one here: http://v2.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/68434/ but I couldn't get it to work for my case.

I need the indexes to go in this type of order:

```
000
001
002
010
011
012
020
021
022
```

except the length has to be variable (and therefore height as well).

Here is my recursion function I've been trying so far:

```
void recurseLoop(const vector<string>& sout, int numLoops)
{
    if(numLoops > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < sout[1].size(); i++)
        {
            //cout << i;
            recurseLoop(sout, numLoops - 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //cout << endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

However the result that 'i' gives is pretty much unintelligible and I'm having trouble getting the correct structure of loops/if statements to get this to work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void recursion(int N, const vector<string>&sout, vector<int>&index, int I=0)
{
  if(I<N-1)
    for(index[I]=0; index[I]<sout[I].size(); index[I]++)
      recursion(N,sout,index,I+1);
  else if(I==N-1)
    for(index[I]=0; index[I]<sout[I].size(); index[I]++) {
      for(int k=0; k<N; ++k)
        std::cout << sout[k][index[k]];
      std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void loop_N_times(const vector<string>&sout)
{
  std::vector<int> index(sout.size());
  recursion(sout.size(),sout,index,0);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use index[i]<sout[i].size()?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you always use `sout[1]` in recursion? It probably should be something like

```
for (int i = 0; i < sout[sout.size() - numLoops].size(); ++i)
```

Comment: I was using that to test, but replacing with a variable didn't do much else. I'll try your solution!

Comment: The output I get from the following code: http://pastebin.com/WPXQchR4 So it looks like it's missing a few 0s and such.